# Objective C - KeyValuePair class?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm looking for a class in Objective C similar to C#'s KeyValuePair (even without the generics). Just anything that has a first/second object. I can create my own with no problem, but I figure if one is already there, then there is no need to re-invent the wheel. I have not had any luck findind one myself... Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So basically like a hashmap, right?

[Use NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Example from [here](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/07/how-to-use-objective-c-dictionaries/):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 

// Add objects to a dictionary indexed by keys

[dictionary setObject:@"A Book about the Letter A" forKey:@"A"];
[dictionary setObject:@"A Book about the Letter B" forKey:@"B"];
[dictionary setObject:@"A Book about the Letter C" forKey:@"C"];

// Retrieve an object from a dictionary with a key

NSLog([dictionary objectForKey:@"B"]);

// Release a dictionary

[dictionary release];
```

Comment: Like this, but only a single instance (hashmap/dictionary contain multiple key/values). I'm looking for a class that is just a single Key/Value.

Comment: You might consider just creating your own "pair" class. Alternatively, you could subclass NSMutableDictionary and enforce a rule of only one pair of objects in your subclassed dictionary at a time.  It does seem odd that there is not some sort of standard "NSPair" object...

Answer (score 5):

How about a simple NSArray?

```
NSArray* kvp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: key, value, nil];
// or, using boxed literals,
NSArray* kvp = @[key, value];
...
NSObject* key = [kvp firstObject];
NSObject* value = [kvp lastObject];
```

You could make a function to wrap `+arrayWithObjects:` (and handle the case of a nil key or value which would trip up the simple approach)

Accessing the elements of an NSArray will probably be quicker than an NSDictionary.

Comment: The semantics of NSArray are NOT supporting the notion of either 'key' or 'value'. you overload the definitions with something you only know as the programmer, which isn't that nice. There IS, however, another class... that DOES support this notion and serves even better with its literals, and in its performance. see my answer below.

Comment: I take your point but Kyle asked for 'just anything that has a first/second object' . A dictionary does not have the same semantics as a key-value pair, so its efficiency or otherwise is not relevant

Comment: Please see my full answer, because NSDictionary DOES support key-value-pair semantics and performance, using a "class cluster" with specific subclass of NSDictionary (__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI) auto-created whenever a single-pair dictionary is needed.

Comment: I have seen your full answer and more importantly I have seen the question, where Kyle asks for something like .NET's [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-5.0). This simple class has only two properties of interest - Key and Value, to be used like `thing.Key`. For NSDictionary it would (I believe) have to be `[[thing allKeys] firstObject]` NSDictionary is a _collection_ of key-value pairs; that doesn't make it a key-value pair.

Answer (score 2):

What about using plain C structs? It's "quicker" than writing an entire class.

```
typedef struct KeyValuePair {
     const char *key;
     const char *value;
} KeyValuePair;

//init like this
KeyValuePair kvp = {"yourkey", "yourvalue"}
```

Things to keep in mind:

- Structs are passed by value.
- ARC prevents using ObjC objects with structs but C primitives are still supported.
- You cannot add structs to ObjC collection classes (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately C struct does not work nicely with ARC and you cannot put them into NSArray/NSDictionary and many other places. it is almost useless

Comment: @BryanChen true, but if you needed some sort of container to pass around without having to create and entire class then structs can still be useful. ARC prevents using ObjC objects with structs but C primitives are still supported.

Comment: you are actually doing it in more C/C++ way instead of ObjC way.

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot aside from defining your own model object containing your "key" and "value" properties, is to use plain old `NSDictionary`, and enjoy some hidden goodness of Objective-C.

First, you can use the shorthand *Obj-C literals* to create a key-value pair like thus:

```
NSDictionary *keyValuePair = @{myName:myAge}; // where myName and myAge are obj-C object instances serving as key and value respectively.
```

or, with constants: `@{@"Motti", @YES};`

This is a true Obj-C instance reference you can use everywhere.

**However**... the real treat here is, you don't lose performance by employing `NSDictionary` because of OBj-C **class clusters**. Here's a snippet from my Xcode debugger:

```
 po [@{@"Motti":@YES} class]
__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI
```

What is `__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI` you ask? it's a special hidden subclass of `NSDictionary`, that serves wherever NSDictionary can - and that almighty Obj-C decided to instantiate, taking note of the fact my dictionary only has one key and one value. This is a highly optimised class, without hash-tables -- a real key-value-pair class.

You should **NEVER** attempt to `[[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI alloc] init]` on your own, because Apple never obliged to its existence, and doesn't expose its definition anywhere in the Foundation APIs - but be sure it is used extensively whenever the language sees fit.

So... just use super-comfortable `NSDictionary`, and let Objective-C do the rest for you.